# range based for loop transformation

Tags: c++11, foreach, c++14

I have the following piece of code:

```
for (int idx : partOrderOptimizer.polyOrder)
{
    SliceLayerPart* part = &layer->parts[idx];
    ...
}
```

How would I go about transforming this into a single range based for loop, alike:

```
for (SliceLayerPart* part = &layer->parts[idx] where int idx : partOrderOptimizer.polyOrder)
{
    ...
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is possible. and how it improves the code? It is not sql or linq

Comment: I'm curious as to whether it's possible, and as to if it improved the code, then I guess that's to the eye of the beholder.

Comment: maybe you can try some C++ linq library, some of them use operator `|` as pipe operator to perform this kind of task

Comment: I'm not looking for a library solution, just a neat trick, if it exists. If it doesn't, it doesn't matter :)

Comment: Maybe implement your own `iterator`?

Comment: This would involve a library in C++, and it is not in `std`.  Basically a range transformer: `boost` has at least one iterator based one, and probably a range one as well.  The syntax should look in the end like `for(auto x: transform( partOrderOptimizer.polyOrder, [&](int idx){return &layer->parts[idx];}))` or somesuch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `boost::transformed`:

```
for (SliceLayerPart* part : partOrderOptimizer.polyOrder | boost::transformed([&](int idx) { return &layer->parts[idx]; }))
{
    ...
}
```